# AirPlay Mirroring games to AppleTV?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, appletv, airplay, fullscreen

So I've been looking into being able to send video wirelessly from my mbpro to my tv. One of my questions is can you actually mirror a fullscreen game to the AppleTV? I mostly only play minecraft and that uses the new os fullscreen.

And does AirPlay mirroring allow closing of the laptop like using displayport to hdmi? That would also help out the graphics card.

So what are the limitations, if any, of AirPlay mirroring?

And if this is not possible, are there any other hardware that will accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hardware supports it, it will work.  My mid-2010 mini doesn't, but my son's mid-2011 mini does support it.  He plays games on the Apple TV + big-screen TV.  He even brings his Bluetooth keyboard and mouse into the TV room, and they're close enough to the Mac mini to work.

Performance is NOT great on the high-framerate FPS kind of games, but should be good for Minecraft.

Even when your HW does not support the built-in mirroring, there are some third-party SW that enables it.  Try AirParrot, Beamer, and Bruce (no affiliation).

Comment: Wow thanks. Ya I have a mid-2011 macbook pro and I've wanted an Apple TV for other reasons for a while now so it sounds like a great investment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh and do you happen to know if those third party apps allow not mirroring, but just running only through "airplay". So that I wouldn't have to keep my laptops screen on. I'll keep researching

Comment: I think AirParrot might have a "2nd screen" option, although in general they are AirPlay (direct-mirror) tools.